# Motion Blur artifacts keep appearing in some of my frames, even when I don’t move erratically

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, artifacts, motion-blur

I am currently using cycles on Blender 3.0, and as for camera animation, I actually use motion data from my phone.

Now, for some reason, in my renders, I keep getting weird, unusual motion blur artefacts in select frames. Ones that I do not move erratically in at all.

Changing shutter settings doesn’t seem to do anything besides overall lower motion blur’s effectiveness as a whole.

See image linked:

https://imgbb.com/PhDrSqy

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.